# Проблема в анимации соседних элементов при hover и keyframes

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, hover

У меня есть блок, внутри которого есть картинка и описание, которое первоначально скрыто. При наведении на картинку блок должен плавно появится из `disblay: none`. Я пыталась реализовать это так, но у меня не получилось. Притом без использования `keyfraymes` все работает. Либо, если анимация при наведении идет на саму картинку. Возможно ли это сделать без JS?

```
.achievements-container__img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.achievements__description{
    disblay: none;
}

.achievements-container__img:hover + .achievements__description{
    animation: 1s show;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас опечатка, непонятно это вы тут опечатались или у вас и в коде так. **disblay**: none

А `display: none` и `display: block` это какой-то принципиальный момент?
Вот вроде так всё пашет. Если я правильно условие понял конечно.

**UPD** вставил `display: none` и `display: block`

```css
.achievements-container__img{
    width: 160px;
}

.achievements__description{
    display: none;
}

.achievements-container__img:hover + .achievements__description{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    animation: 1s show;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s2.cdn.teleprogramma.pro/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/webp_l/fd8181da239a741ce9420cbdbefaa8f8.webp" class="achievements-container__img">

  <div class="achievements__description">
    это Брэд Питт
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, display: none - было обязательное условие.

Comment: Ну, вставил display:none все так же работает.

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо большое